# delete sms programatically is NOT working on android 5.1 and above

Tags: android

I have tried

> getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/" + id), null, null);

even

> getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms"),"_id=?",new String[]{id});

with this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

but it returns 0 each time with no exception thrown. I need help!

Answer (score 2):

From Android 4.4 onward Only one app can delete , upgrade , block or do anything .so in order to work you have to set your app as default messaging app . 
For more information refer here [Official android page on policy change](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

hope it helps ...

Comment: Well. Then is there any guide to make your messaging app as default messaging app programatically? or Android has given this permission to user only to do it manually?